# Why does an object not yet in the DOM lack the on method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this snippet of jQuery that errs:

```
$("<input>").attr("type", "text")
    .attr("name", "wordFilter")
    .attr("placeholder", "Keywords...")
    .on("keyup", filterMyData)
    .appendTo(sidebar);
```

`sidebar` is previously defined as `$("#sidebar")`. `filterMyData` is a function. Why is Chrome Web Developer issuing this error?

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

at the line `.on("keyup", filterMyData)`?

Comment: Which version of jQuery do you use? ["on"](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was added in 1.7

Comment: What version of jquery do you use? "on" was introduced in jquery 1.7 and if you have an older version, it will give you that particular error

Comment: I have 1.6 for compatibility with d3. Thank you, I should have done my research more carefully.

Comment: Fyi, instead of all the `attr` calls you can specify the attributes on creation: `$('<input/>', {type: 'text', name: 'wordFilter', placeholder: 'keywords...', keyup: filterMyData}).appendTo(sidebar);`

Comment: Wow, thank you! I didn't know that one could supply an object as a second parameter. That saves me a ton of `attr` calls.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to do this, in *filterMyData function*

```
filterMyData()
{
    $(this).on(........);
}
```

If it does not work, you are using older version of jQuery. "on" was introduced in 1.7 I think...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
.on("keyup", filterMyData)
```

Or

```
.on("keyup", function(){filterMyData();})
```